# Vector graphic and stroke thickness for logo design

Tags: vector, logo, resize

I want to design a logo that consists of a single word. I already know that word and I also know how I'd like it to look. That is, I don't want to use a commonly available font, but instead draw it as a vector graphic. Also, I'd strokes used for the letters to have the same width. For example say I'd like to draw an 'F' with three rectangles. Then I'd like all the rectangles to have the same width.

Moreover, I'd like to draw my logo and then be able to change the width of the strokes, such as to be able to play around with some values to get a feeling for what looks best.

I tried to use Inkscape to do this, but to the best of my knowledge, I cannot define variables in Inkscape and constrain certain dimensions to be of the same length as that variable. Hence, I'd need to redraw the entire logo every time I want to change the stroke thickness.

What kind of tool can you recommend to me for drawing this logo?

---

Many thanks to Billy Kerr and Scott for their answers. Their answers do not really help me, but I fear that I formulated my question maybe not accurate enough. I ended up using Siemens NX as it allows to define parametric constraints. As visible in the image below, all the vertical strokes of the 'E' as well as the back of the 'E' now have the same width. The definitions for these dimensions are shared across all letters of my logo. They entire logo adapts if a parameter is changed.

Siemens NX can export sketches as PDF files which I can then convert to an SVG file, which in turn can be used in Inkscape to color the letters.

Siemens NX is certainly way to expensive for this to be a generally applicable answer to my solution. I don't know if there is any free/cheaper 2D/3D CAD software which provides parametric constraints. I'd gladly extend this answer if someone is aware of such a tool.

[image]

Comment: Use numeric input to size your rectangles the same- either after or during construction. Then Boolean operations (Pathfinder>Unite in Illustrator) to join the rectangles and then apply/ change desired stroke size/ color ?

Comment: This could be easily done in Inkscape. Nothing to stop you.  You can scale and resize rectangles numerically, and you can set stroke widths numerically.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've added an update. This is also possible in Inkscape.

Comment: You can do this in inkscape too by making lines instead of boxes then stroke width is our variable, use transform to skew. Anyway if you want a cheaper tool than NX for this then see [solve space](https://solvespace.com/index.pl) (NX costs about 300$ a month, makes adobe subscription seem cheap by comparasion). Anyway yes inkscape nor illustrator isnt meant for this kind of stuff.

Comment: FreeCAD (the Sketcher workbench specifically) has constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a low (no) cost alternative, you can do this in [SolveSpace](https://solvespace.com/index.pl) too. Solvespace isn't as nice to use as NX, Catia, Creo, Fusion 360 or SolidWorks. But yeah nothing wrong with using NX for this if it really solves your problem (though for most users its cost prohibitive to use NX for this).

[image]

SolveSpace exports SVG natively, although the GUI has some room for improvement.

Though to be honest you might want to do this in javascript in a browser too.

PS: I'm mainly posting this so that graphic designers get what they are missing.

Comment: By the way when you talk to a person who does direct modelling they look at you askew when you suggest using a solver based indirect modeller. If you do the inverse they look at you askew and think your stupid for doing it harder. There's benefit for both methods. I can do way more complexity in a direct modeller, but doing changes can be painful.

Comment: " I'm mainly posting this so that graphic designers get what they are missing." Could you elaborate, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @HashimAziz there is a alternate way to draw, and that is not to draw but instead describe your border constrains and let the computer draw. A lot of things are easier to draw thisway.

Answer (score 6):

This *should* be possible in most vector applications. I know it is in **Illustrator** and I assume it would be as easily accomplished in **Inkscape**.

The *problem* one may face would be due to the *artwork itself*. For simple forms, all it takes is a shape which is thin. Then applying a stroke to that thin shape. And subsequently adjusting the stroke.

As an example, an F constructed in Illustrator consisting of 3 thin rectangles. The rectangles aren *not* even joined or connected in any way. They are merely aligned to each other.

[image]

For this example, to keep the rectangle widths consistent. I merely drew one rectangle, then copied it twice, and changed the lengths, rotating a copy for the vertical.

More complex artwork *may* present overlap or spacing issues. It's somewhat impossible to be definitive without an idea of the general forms to be drawn. *Typically* as the weight of forms increases the *spacing* between forms also need to be adjusted. You *may* be expecting a bit too much dynamic ability for Ideation. Ideation often takes more manual adjusting.

Answer (score 4):

Numerical input for rectangle width/height and stroke width is possible in Inkscape.

Here's an example. Original rectangle shapes on the left, forming a letter F. Unified shapes on the right with stroke applied.

[image]

Edit:

After your updated image, this would also be possible using an Offset LPE (Live Path Effect) in Inkacape. There are other possibilities too, such as using clones, possibly even just using strokes. There are many ways. Anyway here's the Offsett LPE example

[image]

Using strokes

[image]